# Run Score in a python quiz game

Tags: python

I was writing my first project in python : a quiz with questions, answers and final score

```
question1 = 'When python was created?: '
question2 = 'Who wrote python?: '
question3 = 'How we call an anonymous functions in python?: '

answer1 = '1991'
answer2 = 'Guido van Rossum'
answer3 = 'lambda'

score1 = '10'
score2 = '20'
score3 = '30'

result1 = score1
result2 = score2
result3 = score3
result4 = score1 + score2
result5 = score1 + score3
result6 = score2 + score3
result7 = score1 + score2 + score3
result8 = 0

# Questions

print(question1)
ans1 = input('Enter your answer: ')
print()

print(question2)
ans2 = input('Enter your answer: ')
print()

print(question3)
ans3 = input('Enter your answer: ')
print()

# Answers

if ans1 == answer1:
    print('Correct')
    print('Your score is: ', score1)
else:
    print('False')
    print('Your score is: 0')

if ans2 == answer2:
    print('Correct')
    print('Your score is: ', score2)
else:
    print('False')
    print('Your score is: 0')

if ans3 == answer3:
    print('Correct')
    print('Your score is: ', score3)
else:
    print('False')
    print('Your score is: 0')

print()

# Final Score

if score1 == True:
    print('Your score is: ', result1)
elif score2 == True:
    print('Your score is: ', result2)
elif score3 == True:
    print('Your score is: ', result3)
elif score1 and score2 == True:
    print('Your score is: ', result4)
elif score1 and score3 == True:
    print('Your score is: ', result5)
elif score2 and score3 == True:
    print('Your score is: ', result6)
elif score1 and score2 and score3 == True:
    print('Your score is: ', result7)
else:
    print('Your score is: ', result8)
```

I believe the final score section is partially correct, but I can't the appropriate statement to print the final score / result when running the code (Currently I am using the score statements but I know it's wrong because I have already run the code...)

Do you know what I should do to correct my code?

Comment: You could simplify it by use a var. *total* to check and add up each correct answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
question1 = 'When python was created?: '
question2 = 'Who wrote python?: '
question3 = 'How we call an anonymous functions in python?: '

answer1 = '1991'
answer2 = 'Guido van Rossum'
answer3 = 'lambda'

score1 = 10
score2 = 20
score3 = 30

result1 = score1
result2 = score2
result3 = score3

# Questions

print(question1)
ans1 = input('Enter your answer: ')
print()

print(question2)
ans2 = input('Enter your answer: ')
print()

print(question3)
ans3 = input('Enter your answer: ')
print()

# Answers

if ans1 == answer1:
    print('Correct')
    print('Your score is: ', score1)
else:
    print('False')
    print('Your score is: 0')

if ans2 == answer2:
    print('Correct')
    print('Your score is: ', score2)
else:
    print('False')
    print('Your score is: 0')

if ans3 == answer3:
    print('Correct')
    print('Your score is: ', score3)
else:
    print('False')
    print('Your score is: 0')

print()

# Final Score
final_score = 0
final_score += score1 if ans1 == answer1 else 0
final_score += score2 if ans2 == answer2 else 0
final_score += score3 if ans3 == answer3 else 0

print('Your score is: ', final_score)
```